# RabbitMQ python redirecting to file not work

Tags: python, redirect, rabbitmq

I am practicing RabbitMQ through [Official documents tutorial 4](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html) on my MacBook

This is the final section code:
`emit_log_direct.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='direct_logs', exchange_type='direct')

severity = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 'info'
message = ' '.join(sys.argv[2:]) or 'Hello World!'
channel.basic_publish(
    exchange='direct_logs', routing_key=severity, body=message)
print(" [x] Sent %r:%r" % (severity, message))
connection.close()
```

and `receive_logs_direct.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='direct_logs', exchange_type='direct')

result = channel.queue_declare(queue='', exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue

severities = sys.argv[1:]
if not severities:
    sys.stderr.write("Usage: %s [info] [warning] [error]\n" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)

for severity in severities:
    channel.queue_bind(
        exchange='direct_logs', queue=queue_name, routing_key=severity)

print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body))


channel.basic_consume(
    queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

If I run :

```py
python receive_logs_direct.py info warning error
```

it works fine, messages will show on screen

but if I add redirection like tutorial

```py
python receive_logs_direct.py warning error > logs_from_rabbit.log
```

there is nothing write on `logs_from_rabbit.log` file

and I trying `tee`, the result is same, nothing to show

```
python receive_logs_direct.py warning error | tee logs_from_rabbit.log
```

but if I annotation `receive_logs_direct.py` last line `channel.start_consuming()`, print will working

maybe where I made mistake?